# Set autonumber for DataTable after it already has data

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the following code to add an autonumber column to a `DataTable`:

```
public void AddAutoIncrementColumn(DataTable dt)
{
   DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
   column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
   column.AutoIncrement = true;
   column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
   column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
   dt.Columns.Add(column);
}
```

However, this value will be blank for all rows that are already in the table; it seems that the AutoIncrement is only triggered for new rows that are added after this column has been added.  Is there a way to set autonumber values for the rows that already exist?

Comment: You could upate all exisiting rows after you have added the column.

Comment: Can you not add the column _before_ you add the data?

Comment: @DStanley, there are some cases where I can't add it first, such as using `OleDbDataAdapter.Fill()`.

Comment: @sigil This is a good question. If you come from a SQL Server background, you expect a the values of an autoincrement (IDENTITY in SQL) column newly added to an existing table to be populated, without intervention. It's not the case in ADO datatables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to trigger the `AutoIncrement` functionality when the rows are already in the table. But you could update the table manually easily:

```
public void AddAutoIncrementColumn(DataTable dt)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
    column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
    dt.Columns.Add(column);
    int index = -1;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        row.SetField(column, ++index);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do it using LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

I made a change to @Programnik solution.

```
DataTable dt = LoadDataTable();
using (DbDataReader dr = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    //Get Original Datatable structure
    dt = dt.Clone();

    // Add Auto Increment Column called ID
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID")
    {
        AutoIncrement = true,
        AllowDBNull = false,
        AutoIncrementSeed = 1,
        AutoIncrementStep = 1,
        DataType = typeof(System.Int32),
        Unique = true
    });

    // Change Auto Increment Column Ordinal Position to 0 (ie First Column)
    dt.Columns["TabID"].SetOrdinal(0);

    // Re-load original Data
    dt.Load(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an easier way which doesn't require looping through all the rows.  There is a method on Datatable called CreateDataReader.  So, clone your original datatable, add the identity column, create a datareader from the original table, then load the cloned table with the data reader.  This will generate numbers in the identity column, eg

```
// original data table
DataTable origDT;

// create a reader
DataReader dr = origDT.CreatDataReader();

//clone original
DataTable clonedDT  = origDT.Clone();

//add identity column
clonedDT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(){AutoIncrement=true});

//load clone from reader, identity col will auto-populate with values
clonedDT.Load(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me I was trying to get the unique values from another table and have them have a new ID.

```
        DataTable FinalNest = new DataTable();
        FinalNest.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CuttingPlan", typeof(int)) { AutoIncrement = true, AutoIncrementSeed = 1, AutoIncrementStep = 1 });
        FinalNest.Columns.Add("Material", typeof(string));
        FinalNest.Columns.Add("IncludedPartIDs", typeof(string));
        DataTableReader dr = cutPlan.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Material", "IncludedPartIDs").CreateDataReader();
        FinalNest.Load(dr);
```