# Dataset don't work in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I make online application to store employees information in MS SQL,I use Disconnected model and I made my class for "DataSet configuration" and call method in it in The Form_Load event.
This is the class

public static string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnn1"].ConnectionString;

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(string stored_name, string table_name, params SqlParameter[] prmarr)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stored_name, con);
    foreach (SqlParameter prm in prmarr)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
    }
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, table_name);

    return ds;
```

I set the Connection string in "Web.Config"

Till now all things is ok but when I make insert data to "DataSet"
Error message appear
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is the code I Type in insert Button

```
   int max = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if ((int)dr["Emp_Id"] > max)
        {
            max = (int)dr["Emp_Id"];
        }
    }


    DataRow drnew = ds.Tables["x"].NewRow();
    drnew["Emp_Id"] = ++max;
    drnew["First_Name"] = txtfname.Text;
    drnew["Last_Name"] = txtlname.Text;
    drnew["Country"] = drpboxcoun.SelectedValue;
    drnew["Email"] = txtemail.Text;
    drnew["Experience_Years"] = txtexper.Text;
    drnew["Current_Salary"] = txtcursal.Text;
    drnew["Expected_Salary"] = txtexpsal.Text;

    ds.Tables["x"].Rows.Add(drnew);
```

Where is the problem !!

Comment: I appreciate you may be newer to programming.  One issue with your code is that after you create 1,000 employees, you'll have to load and loop over 1,000 rows, just to get a new_id for the ~next Employee.  That isn't very efficient.

Comment: Yes , I'm newer to programming  but loop it's the problem I comment this part and problem still exist

Comment: most likely you have a datatype issue.  strings are not ints, ints are not strings.  use variable to store values...  current_salary and expected_salary are not strings..I would think.

Comment: I'm sure from the types in the database and I make the two field of salaries string in the database but I still face the same problem , I think the problem with the DATASET it self because the when I comment the loop part another error appear to me
Line 42:         DataRow drnew = ds.Tables["x"].NewRow();

Answer (score 0):

I agree with granadaCoder for datatype issue
add try catch or trace it...
when you are adding to this dataset these "FORM feelds" where you save to DB?

here some code which I do

```
 public class myDAL
    {

       /// <summary>
       /// Collection of SqlParameter
       /// </summary>
       public System.Collections.Generic.List<SqlParameter> __paramList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SqlParameter>();
    /// <summary>
    /// AddParameter -  myDAL.AddParameter(@"@_" + ParamName.ToString(), value, sqlDatatype, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_paramname"></param>
    /// <param name="_paramvalue"></param>
    /// <param name="_paramtype"></param>
    /// <param name="_ParameterDirection"></param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public void AddParameter(string _paramname, object _paramvalue, System.Data.SqlDbType _paramtype, ParameterDirection _ParameterDirection)
    {
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter(_paramname, _paramtype);
        param.Direction = _ParameterDirection;          
        param.Value = _paramvalue;
        __paramList.Add(param);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ParametersClear __paramList.Clear();
    /// </summary>
    public void ParametersClear()
    {
        __paramList.Clear();
    }


   public dataset Here returnDataSetSnippet(out bool hasError){

  //JUST REDO WITH DATASET


   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getConnection.ConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    mySqlCommand.Connection = conn;
                    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (SqlParameter p in __paramList)
                    {
                        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(p);

                     }

                SqlDataReader dbReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        c1 = dbReader["c1"].ToString();
                        c2 = dbReader["c2"].ToString();
                        hasError = false;
                    }

                    dbReader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    hasError = true;
                    //LOG HERE

                }
            } // end using
        }// end using
        return myDataSet;


             }


}
```

here is the usage

```
       public myDAL = new myDAL();

      System.Data.SqlDbType sqlDatatype =   (System.Data.SqlDbType)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Data.SqlDbType), EnumHelper.EnumDescription(Req_Param), true);

   myDAL.AddParameter(@"@_" + Req_Param.ToString(), value, sqlDatatype, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);
```

I have enums with the types

```
 public enum require_params
    {

       [Description("Int")]
       UserStatus,  
       [Description("TinyInt")]
        Mode
     }


  public static class EnumHelper
   {

    public enum Speed
    {
        [Description("5 metters per second")]
        Five = 5,
        [Description("10 metters per second")]
        Ten = 10,
        [Description("15 metters per second")]
        Fifteen = 15,
        [Description("20 metters per second")]
        Twenty = 20,
        //[Description("25 metters per second")]
        TwentyFive = 25,
       [Description("30 metters per second")]
        Thirty = 30
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get the string value of Enum Attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="EnumConstant"></param>
    /// <returns>
    /// string enumDesctiption = EnumHelper.EnumDescription(EnumHelper.Speed.Thirty);
    ///  enumDesctiption = EnumHelper.EnumDescription(DayOfWeek.Monday); when there is no desc returns as string the ENUM property
    /// </returns>
    public static string EnumDescription(Enum EnumConstant)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] aattr = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (aattr.Length > 0)
        {
          return aattr[0].Description;
        }
        else
        {
            return EnumConstant.ToString();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Valentin Petkov
I have another part of code for the saving process to the Actual database , I made tracing for the error (Big point) and I see the error occur in this line
42: DataRow drnew = ds.Tables["x"].NewRow();
I wanna to try the Disconnected model method cause it's the required method in this task and I appreciate your code and I will try In my next task (Connected Model)
But till now I still face the same problem.

Comment: try to print tablenames  maybe "x" is not the correct one  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablename.aspx

Comment: you can use compute for short   find your MAX   
 int max  = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Compute("max(Emp_Id)", string.Empty));
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx

Comment: OR you can use AutoID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179724/set-autonumber-for-datatable-after-it-already-has-data   OR  look this code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Table name "x" is a virtual name and I can type any other name , it's just the name for the table in the "DataSet" in the Ram :(
I think the problem int he DataSet itself as compiler didn't find it although I Define it in the Form_load.
What I do now :( I'm so late in this task :(

Comment: I understand "x" is virtual name but did you create it correctly?  just try with 0  ds.Tables[0]